# how extract real time form time.gov in python?

Tags: python, time, ntp

I want to show real time in my program from [time.gov](http://time.gov/). I saw ntplib module and this example:

```
import ntplib
from time import ctime
c = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = c.request('europe.pool.ntp.org', version=3)
ctime(response.tx_time)
```

but I can't use time.gov instead of 'europe.pool.ntp.org' because time.gov is not a ntp server. Also I saw some java script code in page source. is there a way to extract real time from time.gov in python with or without ntplib?

Comment: You really ought use the pool.ntp.org servers instead of bothering the US NIST. I use the pool.ntp.org servers and am talking to five stratum 2 servers that I never heard of. Indeed, getting a single timestamp is so inaccurate that you'd do better running ntp on the system and using the system clock. Put another way, if you care so much about "standard" time you shouldn't use ntplib at all.

Comment: I know there are other good options but I wanted a challenge so I went to this site and and use time.gov instead usual ntp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use urllib to retrieve

http://time.gov/actualtime.cgi

that returns something like this:

```
<timestamp time="1433396367767836" delay="0"/>
```

Looks like microseconds

```
>>> time.ctime(1433396367.767836)
'Thu Jun  4 15:39:27 2015'
```

Comment: can you please show your code for retrieving from the website!

Comment: @hoangtranm see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36965905/174728 for an example

Comment: No longer works as of 3/3/2021. This URL gives the following error:
`Gone
The requested resource
/actualtime.cgi
is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource.`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the goal is just to get official US government time, you could stick with using NTP, and refer to time.nist.gov, instead of time.gov. They're both run by NIST.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the ntp time server was blocked by firewall in our institute's system. So an alternative, in this case, would be to **scrape** time from the website.
You will need chrome driver to run this which can be downloaded from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/).
Here is the working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from datetime import datetime
# Chromedriver can be downloaded from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/
driver_path = r'pathtochromedriver\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
# Reference website for datetime
url = 'https://www.time.gov/'
driver.get(url)
# Wait to respond
time.sleep(4)
# Correct time
timedata = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="timeUTC"]')
# Correct date
datedata = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="myDate"]')
result_time = timedata.text
result_date = datedata.text
driver.close()  # close the webpage
result_datetime = result_date[7:]+result_time
datetime_now = datetime.strptime(result_datetime, '%m/%d/%Y%H:%M:%S')
print(datetime_now)
```

Comment: I think you mean ‘scrape’. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away, like rubbish.